# An honest mistake

Tags: united-states, banking, bank-account, paycheck

I had a check that I had found while I was sorting through papers, and I figured it hadn’t been cashed because it was pretty much intact and still attached to the pay stub. So I deposited it, thinking that if I had deposited once before it would deny the transaction, but the deposit went through. Afterwards, I went through my transactions and saw the exact same amount had been deposited before. After seeing that, I called the bank and told them, and they said they didn’t see the transaction go through twice. When I told them the transactions were months apart, they seemed like they didn’t know what to do. So I called again the next day, and they said the same thing. The check was for $91. I don’t know what I should do now. I don’t want any problems with that. I can’t afford it.

Comment: Even if I already called and informed the bank ?

Comment: Do you believe that you used mobile deposit the first time? And are you sure the same check was deposited before? Or is it possible you had another check for "the exact same amount"?

Comment: So I talked to a person at the bank earlier and she said yes it was deposited twice and that one of the deposits will be reversed so just keep the money in my account I’m still worried though because I don’t know if that solves the problem completely I’m only 21 and I don’t know everything there is to know about stuff like this it’s pretty scary

Comment: See the linked question. Mistakes do happen and not only to you, so this is not so unusual. By contacting the bank you have shown that you did not have an intent to keep the money (not that it would have been that bad if it was the bank who noticed it, as long as you produced the money when requested). Nobody has anything to win by "punishing" you; the worst that you could expect would be some service fee for the extra hassle (and if that were the case, usually the bank representative would have informed you about it, but even if he did not it is still a possibility).

Comment: I think "Keep the money in [your] account" just means "don't spend it, because we'll be taking it out of your account once the deposit is reversed."

Comment: Oh yes, if that is your doubt @chepner is absolutely right. What the bank means by "keep the money" is not "it is yours now" but "we will cancel the operation and it will be as if the transaction had never happened." If you do not have enough money in your balance, they will substract the $91 anyway and it will be as if you had overdraft from your account (including penalties).

Comment: Yes she did say it would be reversed and that since it was the only time this happened that maybe I won’t be in any trouble but she said she wasn’t sure but yes she did say it’d be reversed and once it’s reversed I’d be charged a $20 fee but she said I can get the fee reversed as a courtesy for this just being a one time occurrence

Comment: And you guys have been very helpful just one last question do you know how long that process should take because I don’t want to have to wait a month that’ll just give me anxiety